# Using multi-threading in JDBC batch job

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

We have a JDBC batch job. There are two tables:

- BUSINESS_CONTRACT
- CLASSIFY_RECORD

The table BUSINESS_CONTRACT stores information of business contracts, we classify business contracts every month and store classify result in the table CLASSIFY_RECORD.

The batch job runs once per month, query the BUSINESS_CONTRACT for those business contracts need to be classified and classify them then insert classify results into CLASSIFY_RECORD.

The batch job runs in a single thread right now, and I want to make it runs with multi-threads

How should I write the basic code structure using the dispatcher-worker pattern?

I learn java multi-threading, but found theoretical resources mostly.Now I want to use multi-threading to solve a real problem, but don't know how to write the first line code.

Answer (score 2):

First, do you need the added complexity of multi-threading?  How long does your current process take to run?  Do you have multiple CPUs or multiple CPU cores available on the server you would be running this on, that would make the multi-threading beneficial?

I'm not going to write your code for you, but can give you a few pointers...

How would you do this work manually?  Assume you had these as paper records, and had to split the task with a co-worker.  How would you divide up the work?  Between 2 people or 20 people?  (That's how many threads you could potentially split this into.)

Once you have these details figured out, you can create multiple threads (your workers, using parent "dispatcher" code) - each configured to select only a portion of the results from your query.  You should keep references to each of your threads, and call `.join()` on each of them once they are all started in order to wait for the entire batch to complete.  If there is a large amount of data that will be difficult to split into equal units of work (1,000 records divided into 500 and 500 may require 75% and 25% of the resources for whatever reason), you may want to consider splitting the work into much smaller units (more units than threads), then have the dispatcher continue to feed the units of work to the workers until all work has been assigned.

Also consider, would these split functions of work be truly distinct?  If one unit of work fails for some reason and needs to be rolled-back in the database, does this mean that all of the other units of work need to be stopped and any existing inserts rolled-back as well?

Comment: I want to do this, only for learning purpose. to understand those concepts with real problem.

Comment: currently, it takes 30 mins to run on my laptop and the batch job will be deployed on a Server with 8 CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using batch updates? It will probably make more of a difference than multiple threads doing single updates.